# How to create singleton class of multiple textures in SpriteKit

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, singleton

I have around 30-40 texture atlas that need to be pre loaded in an SKScene, How do I create a singleton class for all of them, and call them and preload them at once. Each texture is around 4096*2048 pixels.

Comment: What stops you from running a search?  An earthquake?

Answer (score 2):

Before you start wasting your time, I would propose that you do some math.

A single image 4096*2048 with 32bit pixel format RGBA8888 costs you 32Mb of RAM.

If you want to load 40 of these in your memory you'll end up with 1.2GB

An iPhone 6 Plus only has 1GB of RAM - and you can't use all of it.